# Why does my JS return NaN on ios but works fine on desktop?

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I'm using Github pages to host my website currently and my function works perfectly fine on desktop but not on my phone(Ios) and other peoples phone(also Ios).

My function is supposed to calculate how many calories and grams of protein someone needs to maintain/gain/lose weight.

my code

```
function lbsToProtein(lbs, weightGoal, cm, age, excercise) {
  var kgs = lbs / 2.205;
  var calorieIntake;
  var proteinGrams;
  switch (weightGoal) {
    case 1: //maintain weight
      calorieIntake = (kgs * 13.397) + (cm * 4.799) - (age * 5.677) + 88.362 + excercise;
      proteinGrams = kgs * 0.8;
      break;
    case 2: //gain weight
      calorieIntake = ((kgs * 13.397) + (cm * 4.799) - (age * 5.677) + 88.362) + 700 + excercise;
      proteinGrams = kgs * 1.35;
      break;
    case 3: //lose weight
    calorieIntake = (((kgs * 13.397) + (cm * 4.799) - (age * 5.677) + 88.362) - 700) + excercise;
      proteinGrams = kgs * 0.8;
      break;
  }
  var calorieIntake = Math.round(calorieIntake);
  var proteinGrams = Math.round(proteinGrams);
    
 //changed this to 2.55 for now until you add maintaining too
  console.log("Protein: "+proteinGrams+"g");
  console.log('Calorie Intake: '+calorieIntake+'cal', (typeof calorieIntake));
  var info = [proteinGrams, calorieIntake];
  console.log(info)
  return info;
  
}

function ftTocm(height) {
  console.log(height)
  var ft = height.split("'");
  //console.log(ft[0], ft[1]);
  var cm = ((parseInt(ft[0]) * 12) + parseInt(ft[1])) * 2.54;
  console.log("cm", cm);
  return cm;
}

function submit() {
  var lbs = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lbs-input').value);
  var age = document.getElementById('age-input').value;
  var height = document.getElementById('height-input').value;
  var fat = document.getElementById('fat-input').value;
  var goal_input = document.getElementById('select');
  var excercise_input = document.getElementById('excercise'); // value given 1 through 3 to switch function
  var excercise = excercise_input.value;
  var weightGoal = goal_input.value;

  var info = lbsToProtein(lbs, parseInt(weightGoal), ftTocm(height), parseInt(age), parseInt(excercise));
  document.getElementById('calories').innerHTML = info[1] + ' calories';
  document.getElementById('protein').innerHTML = info[0] + ' grams';
  document.getElementById('form').style.cssText = 'display: none;';
  document.getElementById('results').style.cssText = 'display: block !important;';
}
```

I've tried switching things from let to var since people have said es6 didn't work on IOS, but that issue was 12 years ago so probably not the problem. Clearing cache also isn't working. Besides that, any tips are helpful. I do have a node module in my website but it's just for animations. I haven't tried it on Android yet either. I've looked at other posts about IOS not working but none seem to fix my issue.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: is your `cm` is showing NaN? if so, maybe height is in string and trying to split `'` maybe it doesn't have `'` `54` -> `5'4`

Comment: "returns NaN" is not a lot to go on. Look for errors in the JS console and reduce the problem to a [mre]. You'll likely solve your problem along the way. And don't blindly change your code based on a random website post from more than a decade ago. Understand what changes you're making and why you're making them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `var ft = height.split("'");`

replace with

```
  let ft = null;
  if(height.indexOf(fapp)>0){
    ft = height.split(fapp);
  }
  else{
    ft = height.split('\'');
  }
```

This error occurs because iOS devices have "Smart Punctuation" turned on which was causing split to not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your values you are getting in `submit()` function through id of each element. When you get the value by id the value is in string format, Chrome and Firefox are smart enough to parse this string to Int or double value but Safari considers this an invalid value. you can do this instead:

```
let info = lbsToProtein(parseFloat(lbs), parseInt(weightGoal), ftTocm(height.toString()), parseInt(age), parseInt(excercise));
```

Also void using var instead use let
[image]

[image]